# Execute directive after a check

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've `<start-login></start-login>` and the directive

```
app.directive('startLogin', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'startlogin.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  }
});
```

I need to execute the directive ONLY after a check, like this:

```
var checkLogin = false //variable
if(checkLogin){
  //do something and DON'T EXECUTE DIRECTIVE
}else{
  //EXECUTE DIRECTIVE
```

How can I do this?
I've also jQuery in my project..

Comment: You should ask yourself if you really need to use directive in this case. For example check this article http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2014/02/09/ui-router-in-angular-client-side-auth/ how to implement login functionality using ui-router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably go with `ng-if`:

```
<start-login ng-if="checkLogin"> ... </start-login>
```

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf#!), like so:

```
<start-login ng-if="expression">
```

ng-if will not render the content of the tag if the expression is false.

Then in your controller you simply set expression to true when you want the tag to be visible. In your example you could use the variable `checkLogin` instead of expression of course.

---

There's also a big difference between using `ng-if` and `ng-show`. The user might not experience it, since the actual difference is that ng-show *hides* the content and ng-if doesn't render it at all. If we inspect the DOM between the two you will see that they look similar to the code below in the different states:

When expression is true:

```
<start-login ng-show="expression"></start-login>
<start-login ng-if="expression"></start-login>
```

When expression is false:

```
<start-login ng-show="expression" class="ng-hide"></start-login>
<!-- ngIf: start-login -->
```

This is the big difference. ng-if completely removes the element and only appends a comment to the DOM. If you use ng-show (or ng-hide), angular appends a class to the element. The class is declared as

```
.ng-hide { display: none; }
```

which only instructs the web browser to not display the element in the layout. The element is still "rendered" though, or *executed* might be a better word, which is the main difference here. This can have a real impact when loading the page, specifically if the content in the ng-if element loads data from the server for instance. It also means that if your directive modifies the DOM and adds sensitive information, then *you should use ng-if*!

Comment: I think "ng-if" is perfect, because I don't want to run the directive if I don't need it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use ngIf or ngShow/ngHide directives,but there is another way to do that.You can use angular.value(...).As you define a global value of that module,inject it in you directive,then before creating directive,you can check your value,then do whatever you want.